# How does this one template compile while this other one gives a syntax error?

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have this template that compiles successfully with g++. When I remove a seemingly irrelevant function, it results in a syntax error.

**Exhibit 1**: This compiles successfully. Note that this is the only content of the file; the template is not instantiated.

```
template<typename T> struct aaa {
    void w() {
        T x;
        x.goo<5>();
    }
    template<float***, char> void goo() {

    } 
};
```

**Exhibit 2**: The following results in a syntax error.

```
template<typename T> struct aaa {
    void w() {
        T x;
        x.goo<5>();
    }
};
```

The error is

```
aoeu.cpp: In member function 'void aaa<T>::w()':
aoeu.cpp:6:18: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
         x.goo<5>();
```

I tried this using GCC 4.8 and 5.2 with the same result. How does the presence of `void goo` influence whether the line `x.goo<5>();` generates an error?

Comment: Both programs are incorrect. The line should be `x.template goo<5>();`.

Comment: It's more weird that GCC rejects this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84f7e882dc6fe22b . Possibly a misapplication of http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.classref#1